# Updating migration timestamps in feature branches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rails-migrations, git-flow

Let's say there's active development in both my main branch (devlop) and my feature branch. Both are adding migrations now and again. Before merging the feature branch into the main branch, I'm going to rebase it onto the main branch.

So it only makes sense for all the feature branch migrations to come after the most recent develop branch migration.

Is there a handy/advised way to do the renaming of these files? I can just generate dummy migrations and reuse the timestamps generated for them -- but I wonder if there's a best/common practice out there that I don't know about?

Comment: Just a question: why do you need to do this? Rails will still migrate them all, regardless of the timestamp. Not sure about Best Practice, but Current Practice is just to leave them alone and let them stay with their timestamps as is.

Comment: You make a good point. it's possible that one of the migrations in the feature branch might depend on a migration in develop, although that won't happen often, since by definition it was written before the new migration in develop was. so maybe the answer is to use my rename solution, when it's explicitly needed.

Comment: What often happens is that people back-merge from trunk into the feature-branch to keep the branch up-to-date (to avoid horrible merges back the other way when done). So it's quite possible that the feature-branch will depend on code developed in trunk... just not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a rails feature to do this for you, but it would be nice to have a `migration touch` command or something. At any rate, what we do these days is just generate a new migration, copy the timestamp and rename the old one. Generally migrations are stand alone enough that the order doesn't matter, but occasionally we run into order dependencies so we need to update the timestamps.

Comment: Heres a [gist](https://gist.github.com/craigweston/6e64f6677b281a3d7534fb8d30152341) for the migration touch command you describe. It updates the filename to the latest version, calls db:migrate:down on the old version and db:migrate:up on the new version.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments on your question, there is no need to change the file names.

It was also mentioned that it won't usually happen that migration is written, depending on an other migration, before that other migration exists. (If it does, your not doing things right). So the need should not arise.

In a rare case where a feature developer would want to merge multiple migrations (where there is a trunk migration in between the feature migrations) (s)he should merge these into a new (or the last) migration. In any case, it's the feature developer's responsibility to make sure dependancies are met.

Doing so could also create some annoying side effects for other developers. The same migration would run again on their database as the timestamp in schema_migrations would not be available.

Comment: I think saying "you're not doing things right" is an over broad generalization. We often have a case where we start work on one migration, and then realize that there is a prerequisite change, so we have to generate another and get it in before this one.

Comment: It shouldn't happen that a feature branch is dependant on a migration in the dev branch, after the point where they diverged. It can happen that on the feature branch you want to "prepend" a migration - I agree -  but that was not the question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. Here is a use case: Often times when we are writing a feature branch we'll need a migration that adds a column and fills it in with some data from other fields and tables. But in the process, we realize the source data is in some way invalid, so we go make a new feature branch to clean up the data and add some constraints, get that merged, and then go back to our original feature branch and continue work from there. Are you saying that's wrong?

Comment: In that case, yes, it seems right. However I do hope for you that this is not a common situation having your data is in such a bad shape that you can't code around it...

Comment: For better or worse, a lot of codebases end up that way, since people aren't as knowledgeable when they start building an application as they are two years in. I've worked on a lot of legacy applications where the data needs to be rearranged and constrained in order to move forward, including some of my own. Thus far, we've always managed to find a way.